# ("AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo' ) [Tkinter]

Tags: python, tkinter

Code:

```
from tkinter import*
from PIL import Image,ImageTk

class Register:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Registration Window")
        self.root.geometry("1350x700+0+0")

        self.bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="Images/waterfall.jpg")
        bg = Label(self.root,image = self.bg).place(x=250,y=0,relwidth=1,relheight=1)

root = Tk()*emphasized text*
obj = Register(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Above is a little piece of code for creating registration form in python and getting the following error. Using tkinter module in python i m creating registration form mean while when i set the background image in window `self.bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="Images/waterfall.jpg")` and error raise i take image from online and set it with height and width.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Login with Database\register.py", line 16, in <module>
    obj = Register(root)
  File "d:\Login with Database\register.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="Images/waterfall.jpg")
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 89, in __init__
    image = _get_image_from_kw(kw)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 58, in _get_image_from_kw
    return Image.open(source)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2878, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Images/waterfall.jpg'
Exception ignored in: <function PhotoImage.__del__ at 0x000001928E23C430>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 118, in __del__
    name = self.__photo.name
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'
```

Comment: Here's the important part: **`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Images/waterfall.jpg'`**. Most likely, the file doesn't exist, or you're not running in the directory you think you are.

Comment: i created a folder named login database that folder contain one folder of images that contains 2 images and 1 file named register.py to run this program all resources are in 1 folder.. so....

Comment: error has been solved thank's man for help!!! @user2357112 supports Monica

Answer (score 0):

I guest instead of using this.

```
self.bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="Images/waterfall.jpg")
bg = Label(self.root,image = self.bg).place(x=250,y=0,relwidth=1,relheight=1)
```

Try this out.

```
self.bg=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="Images/waterfall.jpg")
self.bg_image=Label(self.root, image=self.bg).place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
```

also, double check the file where the waterfall.jpg located.